# Remove Specific Value (Column (Number)) from Column(Name) in Scala Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Input Dataframe ::

## Number | Name

1      |  1 abc you are awesome

2      | abc 2 you are awesome

58     | xyz you are awesome 58

Expected Output Dataframe ::

## Number | Name

1      | abc you are awesome

2      | abc you are awesome

58      | xyz you are awesome

Basically want to remove value of column Number from column Name. It can be anywhere and any number of time.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes But I think its not worth sharing.

Comment: You say you "want to remove value of column Number from column Name", but in your example it seems you are mapping the values?

Comment: Now , is it clear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try this ,

```
val removeNumber=udf((s:String,n:Int)=>{s.replaceAll(n.toString, " "); })

df=df.withColumn(col("columnName"),removeNumber(col("oldColumnName"),col("firstColumn")).drop("oldColumnName")
```

Comment: Here i am not interested in just removing all Number , I only want to remove specific number which are present in Column (Number)

Comment: Updated answer for using column value to replace

Comment: Thank you so much Krishna :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring.

Eg. for your abc 1 column could be:

```
yourdataframename.withColumn("your_new_column_name" , substring($"abc_1_column_name" , 1, 3)).drop("abc_1_column_name")
```

Comment: Nope that is not something I am expecting. See the edited question

Comment: Change only the column names? How many columns do you have? you could still use withColumn and drop. eg. a.withColumn("abc you are awesome", $"1 abc you are awesome").drop("abc you are awesome")

Comment: I have only 2 Columns, Name & Number . I want to remove value of Column Number from Column Name

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like you are trying to map the values of your dataframe, but if you indeed "want to remove value of column Number from column Name" as you say, then you can iterate through all columns and rename each one like so (in Java):

```
for (String col : df.columns()) {
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]",""));
}
```

If you are trying to remove the numbers from your entire dataset, you'll have to `map` each row:

```
String[] columns = df.columns();
df = df.map(row -> {
    String[] newValues = new String[columns.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        newValues[i] = row.getString(i).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","");
    }
    return RowFactory.create(newValues);
}, RowEncoder.apply(df.schema()));
```

Comment: Nope Thats not I am looking for.

Comment: Well, you should then rephrase your question, because that's what you are asking.

Comment: Nope sir that is not something I am asking , I am asking 1 . Column Name have interger value) which can be anything 2. That perticular interger value I want to remove from the second Column (Name)

Comment: I have only 2 Columns, Name & Number . I want to remove value of Column Number from Column Name